# Spring GET same URL but different parameter types

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

so I am creating a User API and I'm trying to call getUserByEmail() before login. My problem is that I get a Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path ERROR.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    System.out.println("Fetching User with id " + id);
    User user = userService.findById(id);
    if (user == null) {
        System.out.println("User with id " + id + " not found");
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{email}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<User> getUserByEmail(@PathVariable("email") String email) {
    System.out.println("Fetching User with email " + email);
    User user = userService.findByEmail(email);
    if (user == null) {
        System.out.println("User with email " + email + " not found");
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Here is the error response I get:

{"timestamp":1460226184275,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"java.lang.IllegalStateException","message":"Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8080/user/fr': {public org .springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.ffa.controllers.UserController.getUser(int), public org.springframework
.http.ResponseEntity com.ffa.controllers.UserController.getUserByEmail(java.lang.String)}","path":"/user
/fr"}

I know my problem has something to do with me having a GET that is the same but with different parameter types. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Combine your mapping methods and have logic in place which will fetch use depending upon your id or email address

Comment: Currently as per your logic /user/ does not know if it's an email for id. Either have /user/ email ? Email= and /user/id?id=id

Comment: @LearningPhase I want them to be separate, since each one does something different. How do I modify this so that it knows which one to use?

Comment: Use /user/id/{id} and /user/email/{email}

Comment: Use something like /user/id/{Id} and /user/email/{email}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of PathVariables you can use RequestParams with two different URLs.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", params="userID", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@RequestParam("userID") int id) {
    System.out.println("Fetching User with id " + id);
    User user = userService.findById(id);
    if (user == null) {
        System.out.println("User with id " + id + " not found");
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/user", params="emailID, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE")
public ResponseEntity<User> getUserByEmail(@RequestParam("emailID") String email) {
    System.out.println("Fetching User with email " + email);
    User user = userService.findByEmail(email);
    if (user == null) {
        System.out.println("User with email " + email + " not found");
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

When you call `/user?userID=123` it will invoke the first one and when you call `/user?emailID=something@gamil.com` it will invoke the second one. This is taken care by the params property which is passed in the `@RequestMapping`.